# max_statement_mem work fault in Greenplum 4.2

Tags: greenplum

[how could this happened?,the set 8GB didnt work?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yREcc.png)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a bug with an old version of Greenplum that is no longer supported.

```
    gpdb=# create user jon;
    NOTICE:  resource queue required -- using default resource queue "pg_default"
    CREATE ROLE
    gpdb=# alter user jon set max_statement_mem='8GB';
    ALTER ROLE
    gpdb=# alter user jon password 'changeme';
    ALTER ROLE
    gpdb=# \q
    bigmac:~ gpadmin$ psql -U jon -h bigmac
    Password for user jon: 
    psql (8.2.15)
    Type "help" for help.

    gpdb=> show max_statement_mem;
     max_statement_mem 
    -------------------
     8GB
    (1 row)

    gpdb=> \q
```

Now, logging in as gpadmin, I get the default again of 4GB.

```
    bigmac:~ gpadmin$ psql       
    psql (8.2.15)
    Type "help" for help.

    gpdb=# show max_statement_mem;
     max_statement_mem 
    -------------------
     4GB
    (1 row)
```

And here is my version information.

```
    gpdb=# select version();
                                                                           version                                                                       
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.7.1 build 1) on i386-apple-darwin11.4.2, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on Jan 21 2016 15:09:31
    (1 row)

    gpdb=#
```

Comment: `mercury=# select version();
                                                                       version                                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.6.2 build 1) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on Nov 12 2015 23:50:28
(1 row)`

Comment: So you are using 4.3.6.2, not 4.2.  Try upgrading to the latest version and then try again.